# Async Stored Procedure Call in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How one can make an async call to a stored procedure from another one?

Assume I have two stored procedures, SP1 and SP2 (this is a long running stored procedure, takes much time to execute, and doesn't return any result).

The stored procedure SP1 is defined like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1
AS
BEGIN

  --custom business logic

  --CALL to SP2, but async

  EXEC SP2

END
```

How could you make a non-blocking/async call to SP like the above in SQL Server 2008/2012?

Comment: Service Broker is the only statement-level asynchrony built into the Data Engine.  Beyind that there's the SQL Agent, but it's *very* hard to use like this.

Comment: See [Asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/)

Answer (score 5):

There  was once I tried to achieve this by wrapping the stored procedure into Job, and then Calling the job in the procedure through sp_start_job system sp.

```
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'Job name' ;
```

Comment: Works as long as there are no arguments.

Comment: Works as long as you're a sysadmin.

Answer (score 3):

> Blockquote
>   Works as long as there are no arguments. – RoastBeast Dec 22 '15 at 17:30

Here's version with passing parameters

```
  declare @variable -- job name
declare @command -- command

set @command = 'select * from table where data='+@variable

exec msdb..sp_add_job
@job_name =@variable,
@enabled=1,
@start_step_id=1,
@delete_level=1 --Job will delete itself after success

exec msdb..sp_add_jobstep
@job_name=@variable,
@step_id=1,
@step_name='step1',
@command=@command

exec msdb..sp_add_jobserver
@job_name = @variable,
@server_name = 'yourserver'

exec msdb..sp_start_job
@job_name=@variable
```

Comment: utterly amazing. I'm totally making an sp from this just to have it on hand to run lengthy queries without needing to keep ssms open all night. job name from a new random guid.

Comment: Not exactly what RoastBeast was referring to.  Sql Agent management parameters are not the same as the parameters to the stored procedure being executed.