# Is it possible to execute nested stored procedure without waiting for return?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, asynchronous, sql-server-2012

I need to create nested stored procedure. In the following matter.

```
Create proc MyVoidProc 
as
Begin
    Waitfor Delay '00:00:05'
    Print 'This has been executed'
End

GO;

Create Proc TestNestedSP
as
Begin
    Select * From sys.tables --Some select statement that needs to be returned

    Exec MyVoidProc  --This does not return anything.
End
```

Is it possible to return the select statement from the `TestNestedSP` without waiting for `MyVoidProc` to be executed. `MyVoidProc` does not return anything but needs to be executed at the end of `TestNestedSP` because it needs to capture elements from the procedure that it is called from. `MyVoidProc` will take different time to execute, therefore I don't wait to wait for it. Just return what is important back to the user and finish processing the procedure without user knowing about it.

Comment: Why don't you kick off a job that executes the inner SP then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No

But you have other options, one already mentioned, use a job:
[Async Stored Procedure Call in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449430/async-stored-procedure-call-in-t-sql)

other options:
- CLR stored procedures, firing a thread
- running directly from code, not SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Resource Governor`  Option in sql server management studio.
this can manage processors and memory. 
So you can classify your processors into multiple groups and add procedures to each group. So the procedures which are not on the same processor core classification can run as parallel.